# Date is not correct in Ubuntu 20.04 (Chrony is not synchronised)

Tags: 20.04, sync, date

Now I find the time of date is not correct:

> root@hobot:~# date
> Wed 01 Apr 2020 06:04:21 PM UTC

I tried to check the status of chronyd. It is ok and it has some available source. But chronyd doesn't work.

`root@hobot:~# chronyc tracking`:

```
Reference ID    : 00000000 ()
Stratum         : 0
Ref time (UTC)  : Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
System time     : 0.000000000 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000000000 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000000000 seconds
Frequency       : 0.000 ppm slow
Residual freq   : +0.000 ppm
Skew            : 0.000 ppm
Root delay      : 1.000000000 seconds
Root dispersion : 1.000000000 seconds
Update interval : 0.0 seconds
Leap status     : Not synchronised
```

`root@hobot:~# chronyc sources`:

```
210 Number of sources = 23
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^? alphyn.canonical.com          0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? prod-ntp-5.ntp1.ps5.cano>     0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? prod-ntp-4.ntp1.ps5.cano>     0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? prod-ntp-3.ntp1.ps5.cano>     0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? prod-ntp-3.ntp1.ps5.cano>     0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? prod-ntp-4.ntp1.ps5.cano>     0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? prod-ntp-5.ntp1.ps5.cano>     0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? ntp1.flashdance.cx            0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 81.16.177.123                 0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? ntp5.flashdance.cx            0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? ntp8.flashdance.cx            0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? time.neu.edu.cn               0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 196.81.48.144.rdns.as486>     0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 181-215-32-88.rdns.as486>     0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? makaki2.miuku.net             0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? time.cloudflare.com           0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? ntp6.flashdance.cx            0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? ntp.wdc2.us.leaseweb.net      0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? electrode.felixc.at           0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? amy.chl.la                    0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? ntp5.flashdance.cx            0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? tick.ntp.infomaniak.ch        0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? time.cloudflare.com           0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
```